# Do you need to set the non_interaction param in gtag for the default events?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, gtag.js

E.g. In the link below would you need to set the 'non_interaction' param for the
set_checkout_option event?

As this will fire on page load on the checkout but I don't want it to effect bounce rate.

[Event docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#default_google_analytics_events)

```
gtag('event', 'set_checkout_option', {
    "id": this.order.id,
    "checkout_step": 1,
    "checkout_option": "Basket",
    "value": this.order.total,
    "items": this.order_items
});
```

Or

```
gtag('event', 'set_checkout_option', {
    "id": this.order.id,
    "checkout_step": 1,
    "checkout_option": "Basket",
    "value": this.order.total,
    "items": this.order_items,
    "non_interaction": true
});
```

Comment: This looks like GA4? If so, bounce rate is not supported. non_interaction I believe is just for bounce rate, so has no significance in GA4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing I need to clarify is that BOUNCE RATE is calculated based on the number of SINGLE HIT Sessions with the particular page as the LANDING PAGE.

The bounce rate will not tell you how many people arrived at the page and left (drop off), there is a difference.

In your example, this would mean that someone STARTS the session on the checkout page.

If that's never going to be the case then you don't need to set it as a non-interaction event.

Comment: That makes sense, that was a bad example by me, what about something like view_item_list landing on a category page then leaving, should you add a non_interaction or does analytics know as its a default event?

Comment: If you're using from the default list provided then you don't need to attach a non-interaction flag to them, it will be taken care of depending on the event. e.g. your view list event will be a non-interaction one.